# Weird ConEmu Gvim resize border on gvim spawn

Tags: gvim, conemu

I create a gvim instance on a ConEmu window using this line:

```
gvim --windowid !ConEmuBackHWND! -new_console
```

And i get a weird huge white border that acts like a resize handle in gvim:

[image: Weird border]

If i resize the ConEmu window this border is gone.
How could i fix this? Is this a ConEmu problem or a gvim one?
It could be related to some little whitespace border problem that gvim has, but it is always less than a char size..
In this case its huge and it is really frustrating to see it like this.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1: After playing with various sizes on the ConEmu root window, i observed that the initial white border width and height always remain the same! (Not proportionally to the viewable GVim window, but exactly the same with each ConEmu window size i tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writting a little test program that creates a child window and attaching
gvim with the --windowid flag to this child window, i have the same results.
Its a gvim problem, not a ConEmu one.

EDIT:

I found the vim bug and fixed it. It is included in patch 7.4.8.874

Comment: Exactly. Also gvim resizes with some integral steps... https://github.com/Maximus5/gvim-inside

Comment: I am reverse enginering gvim to find a solution to this problem. I'll update this thread with my fork on any results.